# Is it possible to refresh the whole page using an updateprogress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I'm trying to implement a reinitialization button in my page which is linked to an UpdatePanel (AsyncPostBackTrigger). When i click on the button, it deals with an UpdateProgress.

The problem is that, because the reinitialization button is linked with an update panel, it cannot reinitialize what is outside of the UpdatePanel.

Is there a way to do some changes to the controls outside of the UpdatePanel without adding an UpdatePanel for the whole page ? In this case, i want to reinitialize the DropDownLists, the Textbox and the Repeater contained in the UpdatePanel.

[How the page is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjKwu.png)

ASPX code :

```
<body style="padding: 50px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="test"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="AllDemandsTypeHfi"></asp:HiddenField>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-page-title">Création de demande</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-primary">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-heading">Configuration de la recherche</asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-body">
                <asp:Table runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="BankRow">
                        <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label runat="server">Banque : </asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="BankDdl" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BankDdl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label runat="server">Famille : </asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="FamilyDdl" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FamilyDdl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label runat="server">Motif : </asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MotiveDdl" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MotiveDdl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label runat="server">Sous-motif : </asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="SubmotiveDdl" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SubmotiveDdl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Label runat="server">Mots-clés : </asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="KeywordsTbx" data-target="#modalSuggestions" data-toggle="modal"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div id="keywordsTbxSuggestions"></div>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="KeywordsSearchHfi"></asp:HiddenField>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                <br />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ResearchBtn" Text="Rechercher" OnClick="ResearchBtn_Click" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ReinitializeBtn" Text="Réinitialiser" OnClick="ReinitializeBtn_Click" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ResultsUpnl" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-primary">
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-heading">Résultat de la recherche </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="panel-body">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResultsLb" Text="Veuillez sélectionner les critères de recherche, puis cliquer sur Rechercher."></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ResultsRpt">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<b>Type de demande</b>"></asp:Label>
                                <table>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel runat="server">
                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </table>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ResearchBtn" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ReinitializeBtn" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UppDemandsResult" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Loader:LoaderComponent ID="UcLoadingProgess" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind :

```
private void HandleReinitialization()
{
    this.ResultsLb.Text = DemandCreationConstants.ResearchDefaultText;
    this.familyDdlSelectedValue = string.Empty;
    this.motiveDdlSelectedValue = string.Empty;
    this.submotiveDdlSelectedValue = string.Empty;
    this.LoadFamilies(true);
    this.LoadMotives(false);
    this.LoadSubmotives(false);
    this.ResultsRpt.DataSource = null;
    this.ResultsRpt.DataBind();
    this.KeywordsSearchHfi.Value = string.Empty;
    this.KeywordsTbx.Text = string.Empty;
    LogServiceInstance.Debug("L'utilisateur " + UserSession.UserLogOn + " a réinitialisé la recherche.");
}
```

*HandleReinitialization is launched by the event ReinitializeBtn_Click*.

Comment: UpdatePanel is only for refreshing things in the UpdatePanel. You either need to put everything into the UpdatePanel that you wish to update, or better yet, don't use an UpdatePanel at all because they're terrible. Instead, use techniques like [XMLHttprequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to interact with the server once the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. For some reasons, i must use UpdatePanel in this case. And i totally agree with you, UpdatePanel is a very complicated control to handle.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly, you will need to create UpdatePanel2 and add whatever controls into it, then in the button Click() method of the first UpdatePanel1 invoke the **Update()** method.

```
UpdatePanel2.Update();
```

**Update:**
Make sure you set the UpdateMode of UpdatePanel2 to "Conditional"

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            // Your controls
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me to deal with the problem. Actually, your solution needs also to add "UpdateMode='Conditionnal'" in the UpdatePanel tag.

Comment: You're welcome, yes you need Conditional just you like had in UpdatePanel1. I thought you already knew that :) I modified my answer.